# Mock.Verify does not identify call made to mock service provided by IServiceProvider

Tags: .net-core, moq

I'm trying to write an integration test for a service method.  The test compiles and runs without error, but it says that the number of calls that match the predicate are 0.

Test setup:

```
            [TestCase]
            public void Save_Submission_Processing_And_ClientGroupMapping_Type()
            {
                Mock<ISubmissionRepository> submissionRepositoryMock = new Mock<ISubmissionRepository>();

                submissionRepositoryMock.Setup(x => x.GetOne(It.IsAny<Guid>())).Returns(QueryResult<Submission>.Ok(new Submission()));


                IServiceCollection services = new ServiceCollection();
                services.AddSingleton(x => submissionRepositoryMock.Object);


                ClientGroupMappingService clientGroupMappingService = new ClientGroupMappingService(services.BuildServiceProvider());

                clientGroupMappingService.ProcessClientGroupMappingImport(Guid.NewGuid());

                submissionRepositoryMock.Verify(c => c.Save(It.Is<Submission>(d => d.SubmissionStatus == SubmissionStatus.Processing)), Times.Once);
            }
```

Unit under test:

```
public class ClientGroupMappingService : IClientGroupMappingService
{
    private readonly ISubmissionRepository _submissionRepository;

    public ClientGroupMappingService(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        _submissionRepository = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ISubmissionRepository>();
    }

    public void ProcessClientGroupMappingImport(Guid submissionID)
    {
        Submission submission = _submissionRepository.GetOne(submissionID).Value;

        submission.SubmissionStatus = SubmissionStatus.Processing;
        _submissionRepository.Save(submission);

        // ..other stuff
    }
}
```

```
Moq.MockException : 
    Expected invocation on the mock once, but was 0 times: c => c.Save(It.Is<Submission>(d => (int)d.SubmissionStatus == 2))
```

So Verify should see that the call was made to Save, and the param passed to Save matches the condition in the supplied predicate. My knee-jerk reaction is that once I pull the object out of the mock using submissionRepositoryMock.Object, I am no longer tracking the Mock, so calls to the Object are not going to register on the Mock.  But if this is the case, what is the correct way to verify that my method made the required call?

Comment: Hey Sean, it looks like an equality failure. Is SubmissionStatus an enum, struct or a class? If it's a class, is SubmissionStatus.Processing a factory method that creates a new SubmissionStatus instance each time it's invoked?

Comment: SubmissionStatus is an enum

Answer (score 0):

The issue was in the "// ...other stuff" that I took out for brevity.

Later on in the method, the SubmissionStatus is updated again, and Mock.Verify only seems to be evaluating the REFERENCE to the object that was passed into the Save call as opposed to the VALUE, as all of the Invocations of Save show that it was called with SubmissionStatus.Success (which isn't actually true).

Hope this makes sense and helps anyone with a similar problem.